# MVC - ActionLink - The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm experiencing a problem with matching an ID from my view to my controller.

When a user selects edit, it will be directing towards an Edit page, with the ID of the row selected being passed through to the controller, however it errors with "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type" Even when I try to hard code the "id=#" it still counts as null.

My View:

```
@model Mvc4_Development_Test.Models.Customer.CustomerDTO
@using Mvc4_Development_Test.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers Index";
    Mvc4_Development_Test.Models.Customer.CustomerListBO tblHeader = Model.CustomerList.FirstOrDefault( );
}

<h2 style="text-align:center">Customers Index</h2>

<br />

@using ( Html.BeginForm( "ViewCustomer" , "Customer" , FormMethod.Get , new { id = "fm_SearchFilter" } ) )

{
    <fieldset style="margin-left: 110px;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor( model => model.searchFunction.Customer_Name )
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor( model => model.searchFunction.Customer_Name )


            @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.searchFunction.Stat_ID , new SelectList( Model.StatList , "Stat_ID" , "Stat_Desc" , Model.searchFunction.Stat_ID ) )

            <input type="submit" value="Search" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <a href="./CreateCustomer"><input type="button" value="Create Customer" /></a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
@*Display Table Data*@
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: white; font-weight: 500;">
    <tr>
        @*Display Table Header Names*@
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => tblHeader.Customer_Name )</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => tblHeader.Customer_School )</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => tblHeader.Customer_Email )</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => tblHeader.Service_Name )</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => tblHeader.Customer_RegDate )</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => tblHeader.Staff_Name )</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => tblHeader.Stat_ID )</th>
        <th>Options</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => tblHeader.Date_Edited )</th>
    </tr>

    @* Display a table of Customers *@
    @foreach ( Mvc4_Development_Test.Models.Customer.CustomerListBO member in Model.CustomerList )
    {
        <tr>
            @*Customers Title and Name*@
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Title_Desc )
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Customer_Name )
            </td>
            @*Customers School Choice*@
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Customer_School )
            </td>
            @*Customers Email Address*@
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Customer_Email )
            </td>
            @*Display List of Customer Services*@
            <td>
                <ul style="list-style: none;">
                    @for ( var x = 0; x < member.GetCustomerServiceList.Count; x++ )
                    {
                        <li>@Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.GetCustomerServiceList [ x ].Service_Name )</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </td>
            @*Customer Registration Dates*@
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Customer_RegDate )
            </td>
            @*Contacting Staff Member*@
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Staff_Name )
                <br />
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Department_Name )
            </td>
            @*Customers Status Description*@
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Stat_Desc )
            </td>
            @*Display Button Options*@
            <td>
                @*Customer Block/Unblock Button*@
                <button>
                    @Html.ActionLink( ( member.Stat_ID == ( int )Status.Active ) ? "Block" : "Unblock" , "CustomerStatus" , "Customer" , new { id = member.Customer_ID , status = @member.Stat_ID } , null )
                </button>
                @*Customer Edit Button*@
                <button>
                    @Html.ActionLink( "Edit" , "EditCustomer" , "Customer" , new { id = member.Customer_ID } )
                </button>
                @*Customer Delete Button*@
                <button>
                    @Html.ActionLink( "Deleted" , "CustomerStatus" , "Customer" , new { id = @member.Customer_ID , status = ( int )Status.Deleted } , null )
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => member.Date_Edited )
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My Customer Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditCustomer( int id )
        {

            CustomerDTO dto = new CustomerDTO( );

            var std = dto.CustomerList.Where( s => s.Customer_ID == id ).FirstOrDefault( );

            if ( id > 0 ) { 

                dto.Customer = cDAL.GetCustomerByID(id );

                return View( nameof( EditCustomer ) , dto.Customer );
            }
            else
            {
                return View( nameof( ViewCustomer ));
            }
        }
```

My Model

```
public int Customer_ID { get; set; }

public string Customer_Name { get; set; }

public string Customer_School { get; set; }
```

I can't have it as a nullable field as it's an ID on the Database.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the generated address look ok?

Comment: Sorry What do you mean?

Comment: The rendered ActionLink's address.

Comment: The rendered ActionLink goes to the EditCustomer , Customer(Controller) and I'm hoping it uses the Customer_ID as the id variable set

Comment: Right, but post the rendered link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by adding a null where next to the valueObject I.E:

```
<button>
@Html.ActionLink( "Edit" , "EditCustomer" , "Customer" , new { id = member.Customer_ID }, null )
</button>
```